# Storing mouse clicks on a project into an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

I have this project that the user clicks on a 5x5 grid to try and find a treasure but i was wondering how to implement a code that stores where the person clicks on into an array and saves it. So that theres multiple attempts and that it doesnt let the user select the same location twice.

```java
row = getClickRow(panel);
col = getClickColumn(panel);

while ((row < 0 || col < 0) && !(pRow == row && pCol == row))  // Out of bounds error check
{
    row = getClickRow(panel);  // asks user to click once again
    col = getClickColumn(panel);
}

if (pRow != row || pCol != col) {
    pRow = row;
    pCol = col;

    ret = verifyPos(treasureX, treasureY, row, col);

    if (row > -1 && col > -1) {
        if (ret)
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(col * 100 + 51, row * 100 + 51, 99, 99);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `java.awt.Point` class, this can be stored in a `List` (ie `ArrayList`) and you can use [`MouseEvent#getPoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getPoint()) to retrieve an instance of `Point` represented by the `MouseEvent`.  Having said that, you could also just use the `Point` class and keep the cell/grid locations in the array instead, which would probably be easier to compare

Comment: Are you using a Swing GUI library? If so, this code looks a bit worrisome, mixing mouse listening with painting directly. Where are you getting that Graphics object, by the way? And yes, I second @MadProgrammer's wise recommendations.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter . No im not using the Swing GUI library, the drawing panel is on a separate class and its calling the drawing panel to get the mouse clicks.

Comment: Is the "drawing panel" a JPanel?

Comment: yes @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: Then you ***ARE*** using the Swing GUI library. Look at the JPanel API and you'll see the full class name is `javax.swing.JPanel` -- Swing

Comment: oh ok my apologies, we didnt cover Swing GUI libraries and drawing panel much in class so im trying to learn about it while doing this project.

Comment: So again, don't do your mouse listening with your painting, and a while loop is inviting trouble as this sort of loop does not work well with an event-driven GUI.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to save Point values. Rather create a grid of JPanel, give each a MouseListener, and instead save the grid values of the JPanel pressed. You can also change its background color to whatever value needed within the MouseListener.

Comment: Sidebar: I would not use custom painting and a mouse listener for this. Instead, I'd put `JButton` instances in a `GridLayout` and add an `ActionListener`. This provides two immediate advantages. 1) The `ActionEvent` when one is clicked, can point back the the source (the button) of the event. and.. 2) Once a button is selected, you can call `button.setEnabled(false);` to ensure it looks different, and will not fire an event even if clicked.